# Why isn't this showing all rows in a left join?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, units and unit_hits.  Table units shows all available topics.

```
id | unit_name    
1  | unit_name1
2  | unit_name2
3  | unit_name3
4  | unit_name4
```

Table unit_hits shows any topics hit within a given week.

```
id | unit_name   | hit_count  | week
1  | unit_name1  | 1          | 3
2  | unit_name2  | 5          | 3
```

I thought by doing a left join I can list all unit_names from table units and then a hit_count from unit_hits based on what week it is.

So my results would, or should, look like:

```
unit_name  | hit_count
unit_name1 | 1
unit_name2 | 5
unit_name3 | 
unit_name4 |
```

But unfortunately, this is not the case with the query I'm using.  It is only displaying unit_name1 and unit_name2 since it has a hit count in week 3.  I think it's due to the WHERE clause but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Any ideas?

```
SELECT units.unit_name, unit_hits.unit_name, unit_hits.hit_count
FROM units LEFT JOIN [unit_hits] ON units.unit_name = unit_hits.unit_name
WHERE (((unit_hits.week)=3));
```

Comment: Why would units 3 and 4 have a hit count of 1, when as you've shown, they don't appear in `unit_hits` at all?

Comment: Sorry, that was an accident :)

Answer (score 4):

You have `unit_hits.week = 3` (with lots of excessive parentheses) in your `WHERE` clause. That means that if no `unit_hits` match is found, that column is considered `NULL` and therefor isn't equal to 3. You can move that to the `JOIN` clause if that's what your actual requirement is.

Comment: +1 : The `ON` clause is applied at the time the tables are being joined.  The `WHERE` clause is applied after the joins are complete.

Comment: Actually, when the ON and WHERE clauses are applied depends on what the query optimizer decides to do. Implicit JOINs in the WHERE clause will likely be optimized the same as if they were explicit JOINs (certainly Jet/ACE optimizes them the same).

Comment: For `OUTER JOIN`s whether the criteria appears in the `JOIN or `WHERE clause is **very** important and there is a logical ordering.

Comment: But you can't predict FOR EVERY QUERY OPTIMIZER the order in which the optimization will be done. That's my point, not that it matters none at all where the criteria are -- my observation is about making universal pronouncements about every query optimizer in the world, i.e., a very precarious thing to do.

Comment: I'm not talking about optimization. I'm talking about logically (as in which results will be returned). From a logical standpoint where the check is absolutely matters and will always be performed in the same order from a logical standpoint.

Comment: Different query optimizers may treat the same SQL differently (e.g., ordering of OR clauses, or parentheses). Some SQL variants have HINTs so you can direct the optimizer to a particular interpretation of the SQL.

Comment: Ok, I'll try one last time. You **CAN NOT** in **ANY WAY** reorder the logical order of the application of the `ON` and `FROM` clause criteria in this case without logically changing the outcome. This has **NOTHING** to do with performance and **NOTHING** to do with the optimizer. They are **LOGICALLY** different.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.  The problem is your where clause.  Just add that to your join condition.

```
SELECT 
units.unit_name, 
unit_hits.unit_name, 
unit_hits.hit_count
FROM units 
LEFT JOIN [unit_hits] ON (units.unit_name = unit_hits.unit_name AND unit_hits.week=3)
```

Comment: When I do this (I'm working in Access), I get the error message: JOIN expression not supported.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry it has been a long time since I did anything in MS Access.  That would work fine in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `unit_hits with week = 3` for `unit_name3` and `unit_name 4` so they are ignored in left join.